# PHP - Restrict cron job overlap with flock()

Tags: php, cron, flock

I have a php script that processes and creates lots of images which is being run every 5 minutes using cron job. I want to be able to limit this so it can only run once at a time and not overlap if each run takes longer than 5 minutes.

`flock()` seems like the best way to achieve this but i am struggling to understand how exactly i should add this into my existing script. My cron job is setup to run the following file -

**images.php:**

```
$array=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Audi","Ford","Alfa","Porsche","Mercedes");

foreach ($array as $car) {
   generateImageCustomFunction($car);
}
```

I want to use a non blocking lock so based on the examples:

```
$fp = fopen('/tmp/lock.txt', 'r+');

if(!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    echo 'Unable to obtain lock';
    exit(-1);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Is `lock.txt' just a plain text file that stores/indicates the lock or is that the actual file i'm trying to run - in this case **images.php**?

Also where about do i actually stick my existing code in the above?

Comment: it's just a file that's named "lock.txt". whehter you actually have text in there or not is entirely up to you. The mere EXISTENCE of the file should be enough to signal that you've already got your script running. e.g. `if (file_exists('/tmp/lock.txt')) { die ("Already running"); }`

Comment: Problem is that if the script dies, file is there so running a second cron wont run image part, flock , when script dies unlocks imediately

Comment: so sorry if this sounds daft but i don't create the lock.txt file to begin with, it's only created when its locked/running?

Comment: just create a file `touch /tmp/lock.txt` it can be empty and do 'w' instead of 'r'

Comment: @BojanT has a good point here. Therefore, maybe have another script/cron which checks the age of the lock file, if older than X, delete the lock file. If you know the script never takes over 30 minutes to run, check if the lock file is older than 30 minutes, if so, delete it. This presumes the original script failed and is the reason why the file still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code goes here:

```
$fp = fopen('/tmp/lock.txt', 'w');

if(!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    echo 'Unable to obtain lock';
    exit(-1);
}

// YOUR CODE HERE    
sleep(5);

fclose($fp);
```

`lock.txt` just holds your lock. You need write access to this file to create it in the first place. And use a unique name for your locking file, so it doesn't interfere with other processes.

Comment: this is actually a very professional solution for preventing overleaps. Not even need the fclose, if scipts stucks by timeout, it can still be re-run