# Are linux crons asynchronous or synchronous?

Tags: php, linux, multithreading, cron

I am new to CRONs. I have a doubt whether crontab command schedules a cron `asynchronously` or `synchronously`.?

What I know and have observed is, the crontab creates a asynchronous process. Irrespective of the last execution, the new `cron` runs. That is, if I have scheduled a cron task every 2 minutes, then even if the previous execution is not over, a new thread will re-run the file.

Am I correct.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. Cron jobs **can** overlap and therefore they are asynchronous, obviously. If this is an issue, you can use lock mechanisms as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26124589/4481667).

Comment: Cron is at the same time synchronous: it captures all output from each job and emails it (to the crontab's owner by default, or to the `MAILTO` addresses if present).  You're right about how the jobs can run concurrently...but I wouldn't say cron behaves in a *completely* async way.

Comment: I agree, but author specified interest mostly in area of overlapping jobs, so I answered from that perspective.