# Is there a way to wait until one PHP script complete before start another instance of same .php file?

Tags: php, wait

I'm running for example script.php via cron every 5 minutes. Sometimes, it is starts twice because first insance still working. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Easy way would be to have it write an entry into a database table when it starts, then remove  it when it finishes. Check on start-up, if the entry is there the process exits. You could just write it to a text file if you're not using a database connection already.

Comment: @droopsnoot, abouttext file you mean something like lock files?

Comment: @Geckon01 You can use a lock file or a database entry. That's up to you

Comment: Obviously doing it this way, you need some mechanism to release the lock - whatever you use - if the script crashes out before execution is complete. Or make sure it can't do that, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally wrap the PHP invocation in a bash script, then use `flock` on that wrapper so that it uses its own file name, and you don't need any sort of explicit lock id or database hit. It locks when it runs, unlocks when it finishes, and quietly aborts if you try to run while it's locked.

Create a shell wrapper like `script.sh` and then in your crontab, invoke that wrapper instead of the PHP file.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

[ "${FLOCKER}" != "$0" ] && exec env FLOCKER="$0" flock -en "$0" "$0" "$@" || :

/path/to/your/php /path/to/your/script
```

So, if the first invocation takes more than 5 minutes, the second will just do nothing. If, for some reason, you need to know that it has skipped like this, you can check for a non-zero exit status.

You can just drop this one line at the start of any shell script and it will make that script exclusive to run. You don't have to touch the PHP code at all.

(Disclaimer: I can't take credit for this little gem, but I also can't find the post where I discovered it.)

Comment: Sounds very much like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124513/php-restrict-cron-job-overlap-with-flock

Comment: Found it, it's right in the [flock man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html)!

Comment: Thanks, thats wokrs fine for me. Nice solution.